# DeepAR Building Product Categories

Tags: pandas, amazon-sagemaker

I have a problem with the understanding of the DeepAR Algorithm.

I tried to forecast the sales of single products with the Algorithm. 
First I tried it for one SKU on a daily frequence but I got the following error message:

```
ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
Invalid type for parameter Body, value: [datetime
```

I thought, that the reason for that error was that I have too many "NaN"- values in my targets. Could that be the reason?
(I didn't apply any categories or dynamic_feats)

I then tried to make the forecast on a monthly frequence, but the result was that I didn't have enough timestamps for the algorithm.

Would it be possible to group my products within the DeepAR algorithm through the "cat" or the "dynamic_feat" operators, so that I would have less "NaN"-values in my targets?

I would like to group the products by different features like color, price or size. Do you know if that is possible, or do I have to do that before I apply DeepAR?

Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the error is thrown by boto (`ParamValidationError`). I suspect that you are not using the correct json-format to send the requests. See an example [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/deepar-in-formats.html).

> I then tried to make the forecast on a monthly frequence, but the result was that I didn't have enough timestamps for the algorithm.

There is also weekly frequency, which you try out. However, DeepAR should also be able to handle NaN values.

> Would it be possible to group my products within the DeepAR algorithm through the "cat" or the "dynamic_feat" operators, so that I would have less "NaN"-values in my targets?

Generally, `cat` is used to assign one or more categories to a time-series. However, I don't see how that should affect the number of NaN-values in your targets. Also, DeepAR does not emit NaNs in the prediction.

> I would like to group the products by different features like color, price or size. Do you know if that is possible, or do I have to do that before I apply DeepAR?

Yes, that's what `cat` is for. The [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/deepar.html) explains how you can encode these category values.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have so many NaN values? Is it because of you not knowing the values of these days or because there were no sales on these days? Before feeding data into an (any) algorithm, you need to handle missing values. If you can replace your NaN values with zero values or any other imputation method, you will have fewer issues.

DeepAR is best when you add more categories ("cat" values) such as brand, color, size, and similar values. DeepAR is using these categories to calculate embeddings that are encoding the "meanings" of these categories as they affect the sales values. For example, if you have 10 colors that some of them are "girly" and some are "boyish", or some are "crazy" and some are "solid", the embedding calculation has the potential to capture these attributes and use them to improve the accuracy of the calculation.

Prices are different often as they can be elastic (applying discounts or promotions), and they should be represented as "dynamic_feat", and you should add their values for each day/month/other series frequency.

If your prices are static you can still use them as categories ("cat") by converting them into buckets, such as "high"/"medium"/"low". This is also a standard method when analyzing the features that you have and transform them to the capabilities and strengths of the algorithm that you are going to use. DeepAR, in this case, is good in encoding categories (static and low cardinality features) and calculating regression to numeric features with possible correlation with the target.